# How to merge 3 arrays in one array using C#

Tags: c#

I have 3 arrays like

Array 1          Array 2       Array 3                       Result

name  value     name value    name value     ==  name value1 value2 value3
abc   1          abc  3       abc  5             abc   1       3      5
xyz   2          xyz  4       xyz  6             xyz   2       4       6

Please let me know if anybody have any solution for this in C#

Comment: add some code to show what you mean and how you would like it to work

Comment: i already mention that i want to create alias for "UnitTest.test" as "t" and want to call the method "t1" using alias "t" like t.t1()..............UnitTest is namespace, test is class,, t1() is method

Comment: is `t1` a static method?

Answer (score 0):

For namespace you can have like this.

```
using ns = namespace;
```

For method you can create extension method and but it wrapper not alias, but can fulfill your purpose.

```
public static class ExtensionsClass 
{
    public static void NameMethod(this ABC t)
    {
       t.ActualMethod();
    }
}
```

For classes, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: c# does not have aliases so thats not possible

Comment: @sommmen didn't get your point. Yes I agree it doesn't support but we can do some heck to achieve it by using the existing features

Comment: sorry it was a reaction to this `For classes, I have no idea how to do this.`